# Concatenate 3 or more column values into a single value, while maintaining dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**

```
type    id  count   date    name
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello
no      B   BB01    Q4 21   hey
```

**Desired**

```
type    id  count   date    name      full
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello     A AA01 Q4 21 - hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello     A AA01 Q4 21 - hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello     A AA01 Q4 21 - hello
set     A   AA01    Q4 21   hello     A AA01 Q4 21 - hello
no      B   BB01    Q4 21   hey       B BB01 Q4 21 - hey
```

Doing

```
df['combined']=df['full'].astype(str)+'_'+df['id']+'_'+df['count']
```

However, the other columns are not being maintained. I am still troubleshooting, any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: The column `full` is not defined in your original dataframe . . .

Comment: `df['full']=df[df.columns[1:4]].astype(str).apply(' '.join,1)+' - '+df['name']`?

Comment: The column full is what is being created by the combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['full'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row['id']) + ' ' + str(row['count']) + ' ' + str(row['date']) + ' - ' + str(row['name']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to obtain your desired result:

```
df['full']=df['id'] + ' ' + df['count'] +' '+ df['date'] +' - ' +df['name']
```

you may need to set some of the columns astypr(str) depending on the types

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I think you are looking for the following:

```py
# Create Test Data Set
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['set', 'set'], 'id': ['A', 'A'], 'count': ['AA01', 'AA01'], 'date': ['Q4 21', 'Q4 21'], 'name': ['h
ello', 'hello']})

# Create new column
df['full'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([x['id'], x['count'], x['date']]) + ' - ' + x['name'], 1)

df
```

Output:

```
  type id count   date   name
0  set  A  AA01  Q4 21  hello
1  set  A  AA01  Q4 21  hello
```